# Soft Delete. Update multiple `deleteAttribute` from joining table?

Tags: php, database, yii, soft-delete

I have followed [a blog post](http://www.prettyscripts.com/framework/yii/yii-soft-delete-behavior) to implement soft delete behavior in yii and it work well.

here's some snippet:

```
class <name of model> extends CActiveRecord {
    public function behaviors {
        return array(
            'SoftDeleteBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'application.components.behaviors.SoftDeleteBehavior',
                'deleteAttribute' => 'deleted_date', // optional, default is 'deleted_time'
                'timestampExpression' => 'date("Y-m-d H:i:s");',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

How do I update multiple `deleteAttribute` from joining table using `SoftDeleteBehavior`?

Comment: Do you mean update multiple rows at the same time, or update columns in other tables at the same time?

Comment: change code in SoftDeleteBehavior class and send attribute whichever you want to delete

Comment: or use afterDelete event in parent class to initiate delete in sub-records ...